# How to render in html after sorting json object

Tags: jquery, json, sorting

I'm getting JSON object which is the result of my query. Now I want to sort the JSON object array in order to display sorted by name or reputation, selected by user.

ALl I need to know now is how does it pass the data to the HTML after performing the sorting?

**Function after user triggered sort by button:**

```
$("#Name").on("click",function()
{
    $(".the-return").slideUp("normal",function()
    {


        getData.responseData.sort('name');//passing to sorting funtion


       // displaying after sorted
        for (i = 0; i < getData.length; i++) {
        $(".the-return2").append("<div class='inside_return'>Name:" + getData[i].name +"</div>");

        }

    });
});
```

**sorting function**

```
 getData.responseData.sort(function (a, b) {
        switch (sortOption) {
            case 1:
                a = a.name,
                b = b.name;
                type = "string";
            case 2:
                a = a.reputation,
                b = b.reputation;
                type = "numeric";
            // etc
        }
        if (type == "numeric")
        {
            // numeric comparison
            return a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0);
        } else if (type == "string") {

            // string comparison
            return a.localeCompare(b); 
        }
        // etc

        return;


    });
```

ABove code, doesn't do anything..

I saw this error in console:  **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseData' of undefined**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you wanted to do something like this:

```
getData = {
    responseData : {
        sort : function (a, b) {

        }
    }
}
```

At the moment getData is undefined and therefore trying to access a member responseData on it results in an error.

Comment: after do like your's above , it shows this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined

Comment: Interesting. Have a look at this fiddle, you can see the sort function is definitely defined: http://jsfiddle.net/GarryPas/qmn78sqf/